# ValueError: Field 'bid' expected a number but got ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am making an Auction website using Django. When is use Migrate command it gives an error "ValueError: Field 'bid' expected a number but got " ".
The code of the models.py file is:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.db.models.fields import CharField
from django.utils import timezone


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.category}'


class AuctionListing(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products", null=True, blank=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    last_bid = models.ForeignKey('Bid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='lst')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='publisher_listing', null=True, blank=True)
    watchers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='watched_list')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    list_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='sortion')
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.item_name} - {self.price}'


class Bid(models.Model):
    p_bid = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    auction = models.ForeignKey(AuctionListing, on_delete=CASCADE)
    bid_date = models.DateTimeField(timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.bid)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    com = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    com_item = models.ForeignKey(AuctionListing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='get_comment')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {self.pub_date}'
```

The code of views.py is:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    # from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.db import IntegrityError
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    
    from .models import *
    
    
    def index(request):
        active_list = AuctionListing.objects.all()
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {'active_list': active_list})
    
    
    def login_view(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
    
            # Attempt to sign user in
            username = request.POST["username"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    
            # Check if authentication successful
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
            else:
                return render(request, "auctions/login.html", {
                    "message": "Invalid username and/or password."
                })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html")
    
    
    def logout_view(request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    
    
    def register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST["username"]
            email = request.POST["email"]
    
            # Ensure password matches confirmation
            password = request.POST["password"]
            confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
            if password != confirmation:
                return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                    "message": "Passwords must match."
                })
    
            # Attempt to create new user
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                    "message": "Username already taken."
                })
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html")
    
    
    
    class CreateForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = AuctionListing
            fields = ['item_name', 'item_image', 'detail', 'price', 'pub_date', 'deadline', 'list_category']
            
    
    
    def create_listing(request):
        user = request.user
        if user.id is None:
            return redirect('login')
    
        
        if request.method == 'GET':
            context = {
                'form': CreateForm()
            }
            return render(request, 'auctions/create_listing.html', context)
    
        else:
            if request.method == 'POST': 
                form = CreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
                if form.is_valid():
                    item_name = form.cleaned_data['item_name']
                    item_image = form.cleaned_data['item_image']
                    detail = form.cleaned_data['detail']
                    price = form.cleaned_data['price']
                    pub_date = form.cleaned_data['pub_date']
                    deadline = form.cleaned_data['deadline']
                    list_category = form.cleaned_data['list_category'] 
    
                    listing_created = AuctionListing.objects.create(
                        item_name = item_name,
                        item_image = item_image,
                        detail = detail,
                        price = price,
                        pub_date = pub_date,
                        deadline = deadline,
                        list_category = list_category,
                        user = request.user,
                    )
                    listing_created.save()
                    return redirect('index')
    
    
    def listing(request, pk):
        list = AuctionListing.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {'list': list})
```

The code of urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("", index, name="index"),
    path("login", login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", register, name="register"),
    path('create', create_listing, name='create_listing'),
    path('listings/<int:pk>', listing, name='listing')
    ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The migrations file(auctions.0005_auto_20211019_1227) is:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.7 on 2021-10-19 12:27

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auctions', '0004_auto_20211017_0907'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='bid',
            name='bider',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='auctionlisting',
            name='closed',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='bid',
            name='bid',
            field=models.IntegerField(default=''),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='auctionlisting',
            name='last_bid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='auctions.bid'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='auctionlisting',
            name='price',
            field=models.IntegerField(),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='bid',
            name='bid_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(),
        ),
    ]
```

```
    Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auctions, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying auctions.0005_auto_20211019_1227...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 823, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 818, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/saif/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'bid' expected a number but got ''.
```

The bid model and field seem to be okay so I don't know where the problem is. Please help me with this problem. I will be thankful to you.

Comment: you you are trying to apply a migration, it would be really helpful to show the actual migration you are trying to run. They're in `migrations` directory inside the app.

Comment: You should include the stack trace in your question and relevant code only, if the issue is with running `migrate` then it won't have anything to do with your views or urls

Comment: I have edited the migration file in question.

Comment: @SaifKhan the migration causing the error is `auctions.0005_auto_20211019_1227` not the one you posted

Comment: @IainShelvington then how to find the one which is causing the problem?

Comment: @SaifKhan it's `auctions.0005_auto_20211019_1227` that's causing the problem

Comment: @IainShelvington I have editied the question and added `auctions.0005_auto_20211019_1227` this file in it. please look into it.

Comment: @SaifKhan You pass `default=''` when adding the `bid` field in that migration, change it to `default=0`. You can't pass a string as a default to an IntegerField

Comment: @lainShelvington I think this solved the problem. There is another problem in this file `raise IntegrityError(
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'auctions_auctionlisting' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: auctions_auctionlisting.last_bid_id contains a value '3000' that does not have a corresponding value in auctions_bid.id.
` Can you tell me how to solve it?.

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py replace the line

```
last_bid = models.ForeignKey('Bid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
null=True, related_name='lst')
```

with this

```
last_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
null=True, related_name='lst')
```

You are typing Bid in string.
There is also one bug in your Bid class

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.bid)
```

replace it with

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % str(self.p_bid)
```

Hope it works
Thank you

Comment: when I use Bid without string it says that 'Bid is not defined'

Comment: Just define Bid class above AuctionListing class.

Comment: I tried it but not working because of foreign key in Bid.

Comment: @SmitParmar - There are many reasons you may want to use a custom user class, django even has a page in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django) about it, and theres no issue with referencing classes by strings in foreign keys.

Comment: @Sayse yeah, we can use custom class. but he had type only pass inside that class that's why he can't use that class as a foreign key. so I recommend him to use an inbuilt class.